# Most efficient way to handle failure retry with multiple possibilities in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am adding code to my iOS app to deal with errors when it interact with a server.   The error handling varies based on type of failure.

For e.g:  The error could be receipt of a non 200:OK response.  In which case, I want to use the response code to determine the retry algorithm

Or the error could be a timeout

Or the error could be based on the value of a field in the JSON body returned from the server.

Also, the error handling would be different depending on whether the failure occurred during registration or during data transfer etc.

I am thinking of having a generic function to avoid repeating code in several places

Basically it will take two arguments
1. A failure code that identifies sub-type of error and 
2. A JSON body whose content will depend on the failure code argument

Is this approach ok or is it better split it into individual functions?

Answer (score 0):

The approach with one function is OK, but as you said, sometimes you will have message as body from JSON response, sometimes you will have error as timeout, sometimes as key from the 200 OK response.. It means you need a parser function which will decide what to pass as the error message, because I'm afraid that you will end up with huge function doing everything at once. I would:

a) *Split this function to parser & error show*

**or**

b) *Do the parsing in the network handler, but it might copy the code across the application.*